# Confused by the `m..n` notation in MiniZinc

Tags: minizinc

I have seen the "dot-dot" notation (`..`) in different places. In the following example, `0..n` tells us the domain of the decision variable (which in this case, are the entries of the array `s`).

```
int: n;
array[0..n-1] of var 0..n: s;
```

Another example would be in the for-loop:

```
constraint forall(i in 0..sequence_length)(
    t[i] = sum(k in 0..sequence_length)((bool2int(t[k] == i)))
);
```

In fact, we can even do something like

```
par var 1..5: x
```

My feeling is that the expression `m..n` is generally used when we define a variable (instead of a parameter), and we want to specify the domain of the variable. But in the second case, we are not defining any variable. So when do we use `m..n`? What is it exactly (e.g. does it have a type?)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m..n` denotes the **set** of (consecutive) integers from `m` to `n`. It could also be written explicitly as `{m,m+1,m+2,...,n-1,n}`.

Using a set as the domain, e.g.

```
var 0..5: x;
```

could be written as

```
var {0,1,2,3,4,5}: x;
```

or (which is probably a weird style):

```
var {1,5,2,3,0,4}: x;
```

but both represents the set `0..5`.

When using `m..n` in a `forall(i in m..n) ( .... )` loop it means that `i` is assigned from `m` to `n`.

A set is always ordered as this little model shows:

```
solve satisfy;
constraint
    forall(i in {0,4,3,1,2,5}) (
       trace("i: \(i)\n")
    )
;
```

The `trace` function prints the following, i.e. ordered:

`i: 0
i: 1
i: 2
i: 3
i: 4
i: 5`